# How do I space images on a page in a similar way as Google images

Tags: html, css

Images displayed in goolge images end squarely at the right hand side of the page regardless of image dimensions or screen size. I was thinking that perhaps it is possible to add some sort of dynamic padding to make images fit squarely into a div? If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

- Define the height of each row and the minimum and maximum width you want.
- Calculate the width of your image if you scale it to the given height.

  - If the calculated width lies between the minimum and maximum width, scale it to this size.
  - If the width is smaller, scale the image so it has the minimum width, and crop it so it has the proper height.
  - If the width is bigger then the maximum, scale it this way and crop it, so it has the right width.

In order to make all the images fit the row perfectly, you might need to adjust the minimum and maximum width. Especially images which need to be cropped anyway can be used to adjust the length of the row.

You can achieve this using CSS (& JavaScript) or by doing it on the server side. If your page width is dynamic, you have to rely on CSS/JavaScript though.